# Where do I get the source code for com.sun.xml.internal package?

Tags: java

Where do I get the source code for com.sun.xml.internal package? It is part of the JDK 7 but its source files are not located in the $JAVA_HOME/src.zip . Generally the JDK souce files are located there but for this case are not.

**UPDATE:**
To answer my own question you can download all OpenJDK source by using executing this and then linking to that source folder in Eclipse:

```
cat > subprojects.md5 << EOF &&
c99a63dfaf2b2f8cc549e65b790a2e7a  corba.tar.bz2
d15561707ce64419f36c18e4fba6cbbe  hotspot.tar.bz2
5b32371928b7aa67646b560e5c89dcde  jaxp.tar.bz2
05f7c3c91f3a6a38316bb4f406798b61  jaxws.tar.bz2
07223640c22b3ea75f3df81876622ba5  langtools.tar.bz2
6d737d1623b83a7acca8c18d0e08dd3d  jdk.tar.bz2
d5e109b7e2b2daab5874d650293321c8  nashorn.tar.bz2
EOF

for subproject in corba hotspot jaxp jaxws langtools jdk nashorn; do
  wget -c http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/${subproject}/archive/jdk8u66-b17.tar.bz2 \
       -O ${subproject}.tar.bz2
done &&

md5sum -c subprojects.md5 &&

for subproject in corba hotspot jaxp jaxws langtools jdk nashorn; do
  mkdir -pv ${subproject} &&
  tar -xf ${subproject}.tar.bz2 --strip-components=1 -C ${subproject}
done
```

Comment: As far as I know, com.sun.* is NOT part of the JDK.

Comment: @stuxNet it is part of the implementation but some of com.sun.* are located in src.zip while com.sun.xml.* are not.

Comment: thx! Didn't know that com.sun.* is actually included in src.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you can download it, but you can view it at several places on the web, like [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.AccessorFactory) or [docjar](http://www.docjar.com/docs2web/s.jsp?q=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.AccessorFactory&t=q&start=0).

If you are using Eclipse then I can recommend [JD Eclipse](http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/) which will decompile the byte code back into source code so you can read it and follow along. You'll lose comments and some other stuff, but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple places in OpenJDK where classes in these packages might reside:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jaxp/file/tip/src/com/sun/xml/internal/

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jaxws/file/tip/src/share/jaxws_classes/com/sun/xml/internal/